# The game ”waiting for the six”

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The game ”waiting for the six” goes as follows: You roll a fair die. If you get anything less than 6, say 3, you wait for 3 minutes, then roll again. You keep doing so until you get a 6. The game is then over (there is no waiting when you get 6). Determine the average waiting time.

So far, I have this

Probability of getting 6 in a single roll = 1/6

Hence,

On an average, we will get 6 once out of 6 times.
Once you get 6 game is done. You do not have to wait 6 min.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The average of the five times you expect to have to wait is not $2.5$

Comment: The question is unclear as to whether you wait 3 minutes when 6 is not rolled, or the [die spots rolled] number of minutes.

Comment: the [die spots rolled] number of minutes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think of this is to let $T$ be the time it takes to roll the first $6$. If you roll a $6$ there is no more waiting. If you roll a $5$ you wait $5$ minutes and are in the same position you started in ... etc

So $$T=0+\frac {5+T}6 +\frac {4+T}6 +\frac {3+T}6+\frac {2+T}6+\frac {1+T}6=\frac {15}6+\frac {5T}6$$